# Big JSON creation dynamically using array manipulation and object manipulation using Lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, lodash

sample final output

```
{
  "triggers": [{
    "all": [{
        "any": [{
               "equation": {
                  "equation array of object"
               }
            },
            {
             "equation": {
              "equation array of object"
             }
        }],
        "all": [{
            "equation": {
              "equation array of object"
           }
        }]
    }]
 }]
}
```

the equation of this is formed using the array which is created using the function below

PART 1: sample output of any one of the equation

```
   equation: {
      "equation array of object"
    }
```

the above equation is equivalent to the equation below which is formed like this

```
    this.numberEquation.push({
      resourceLeft: this.model1,
      arthop: this.model2,
      resourceCenter: this.model3,
      logicalop: this.model4,
      resourceRight: this.model5,
    });
```

PART 2: sample output of the array of objects

```
     "any": [{
               "equation": {
                  "equation array of object"
               }
            },
            {
             "equation": {
              "equation array of object"
             }
        }],
```

here i have used the below format to create it.

is there a way in which this could be achieved dynamically using a loop rather than using [0] and [1] notation for the array.

```
      this.wholeNumberEquation.push({
        any: [{
          number_equation: this.numberEquation[0],
            },
          {
          number_equation: this.numberEquation[1],
          },
        ],
      });
```

here is equation number 3 which is generated from the number equation 3 position

PART 3: sample output

```
        "all": [{
            "equation": {
              "equation array of object"
           }
        }]
```

here is the equation which is generating the above

```
        this.equationthree.push({
          all: [{
            number_equation: this.numberEquation[2],
          }],
        });
```

the final piece is for the whole equation is

PART 4: sample output

```
 "all": [{
    "any": [{
           "equation": {
              "equation array of object"
           }
        },
        {
         "equation": {
          "equation array of object"
         }
    }],
    "all": [{
        "equation": {
          "equation array of object"
       }
    }]
}]
```

is formed using the code below

```
      this.final = [{
          all: _.merge(this.wholeNumberEquation, this.equationthree),
        }];
```

finally the whole output as per the desired sample final out initially state is

```
 "triggers": [{
    "all": [{
      "any": [{
           "equation": {
              "equation array of object"
           }
        },
        {
         "equation": {
          "equation array of object"
         }
      }],
    "all": [{
        "equation": {
          "equation array of object"
       }
     }]
  }]
}]
```

PART 5: the actually code to get this is below

```
  this.finalJSON = {
   triggers: [{
      this.final, 
     }]
 }
```

I was unable to use loops to populate the JSON , if the equation is more the three equation in the numberEquation it wouldn't take it and will not work. JSON as shown in the code, it would work. but is there is more equation like 5 equation. i would have to create another if condition for 4 and 5 and make the JSON. however if there is dynamic way to create it, from the number equation using a loop, it would be great.Also if you suggest a better approach to this would be really help.

Comment: I don't get why you can not use a loop. What's the error?

Comment: how would one go for it ? i tired but it doesn't  push into an json like the sample output which needs to be created, it need to created on the fly along with the number equation. is there a way i could use a loop instead of [0] or [1] or [2] notation and create the json also